# testdroid logcat output missing from some devices

Tags: android, android-logcat, testdroid

When running Android Instrumentation tests on TestDroid, some devices don't seem to show logcat output for the testing app.  (There appears to be some system stuff, but nothing from the app or test runner.)

When tests fail, it can be very hard to figure out what went wrong without being able to see the logcat that happened during the test.

Is this a bug?  Is there some way I can work around this problem?

Comment: You have android studio Beta? (3.0.6 Beta)

Comment: I have Android Studio 2.3.3, but I'm not sure how that's relevant.  With TestDroid you upload your app apk and instrumentation apk.

Comment: You should contact support@bitbar.com, providing details about the run.